# Bash: Fill color on specific part of image

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking for a way to batch process images in bash.

Is there any way to fill up specific part of image?

Example:

[image]

I want to fill up the red part with white color. The red part is always on the top left corner, size is 135x35px.

Yes, Gimp/Photoshop is one way to do this, but I have lot of images and I love automatize things with bash.

Comment: Automation is the way to go. I'm planning on processing a crapily-scanned book. Definitely need some automation here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, use ImageMagick - installed on most Linux distros and available for OSX and Windows.

```
convert input.png -fill white -draw "rectangle 0,0 135,35" result.png
```

If you have many files, make a COPY in a spare folder and try this and it will probably do them all

```
mogrify -fill white -draw "rectangle 0,0 135,35" *.jpg
```

Comment: One more question, is there any way to draw another rectangle to the south-center? I tried to set this by -gravity option, but it seem to be not working. Hmmm.

Comment: Still only on iPhone, so I may have to revise it tomorrow but something like `convert input.jpg -size 135x35 xc:white -gravity south -composite result.jpg`